# Layering in RVG

Tags: ruby, rvg

How can I layer shapes/text in Ruby RVG library? For example, I want to have "Text 1" over "Text 2":

```
rvg.text(0, 0, "Text 1")
rvg.text(0, 0, "Text 2")
```

Right now it will have "Text 2" over "Text 1" but I want to have "Text 1" over "Text 2".

**Edit**

In the following image I add a shape and then the text but the text is still under the shape. Regardless of which order I use, the text is always underneath.

[image: shape and text]

Comment: You are adding them in the order in which they will be drawn. Since you want to draw text 1 over text 2, add it second.

Comment: @Brennan I had some more findings. See the question with the updates. The text is underneath regardless.

Comment: Ok, after a lot of debugging I figured it out. Turns out I was duplicating some of the shapes. What @Brennan said is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As @Brennan specified, shapes will be drawn in the order they are added.